# How to enable debug mode by generating service worker file from workbox cli?

Tags: javascript, web, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm trying to enable my workbox config to debug mode

Usually I just have to set the config in my sw.js file like this

```
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true,
});
```

But because now I'm using generateSW form workbox-cli, I can't set the debug to true

I've tried to configure my workbox-config.js file like this

```
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "./",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{css,ico,png,html,js,json}"
  ],
  "swDest": "sw.js",
  "debug",true
};
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Workbox v5 or later, you'd set the `mode: 'development'` option.

You can view the full list of options in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/reference/workbox-build/#type-GeneratePartial).

Comment: Note that setting `mode` is not possible when using `InjectManifest`, see [Deprecate mode in the InjectManifest config](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2843)